# Insert image in WordPress with HTML5 <figure> tag and caption function

Tags: functions, filters, editor, customization

When I upload an image through the WordPress media uploader and then insert it into the editor, it comes also with the width and height attributes (`eg width="440" height="340"`)

But now I'm using the following code ([source](https://gist.github.com/tomazzaman/b952b3f23dfdbf499e79)) to replace the image tags with figure. Unfortunately the **width** and **height** attributes are missing. Any idea how to insert them to?

```
    function html5_insert_image( $html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt ) {
        $src  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, $size, false );
        $html5 = "<figure id=\"post-$id media-$id\" class=\"align-$align\">";

        if ( $url ) {
        $html5 .= "<a href=\"$url\" class=\"image-link\"><img src=\"$src[0]\" alt=\"$alt\" /></a>";
        } else {
            $html5 .= "<img src=\"$src[0]\" alt=\"$alt\" />";
        }

        if ( $caption ) {
            $html5 .= "<figcaption>$caption</figcaption>";
        }

        $html5 .= "</figure>";
        return $html5;
    }
    add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'html5_insert_image', 10, 9 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width and height are `[1]` and `[2]`. So these are added on the img tag. If a theme has [html5 caption support](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/04/15/html5-galleries-captions-in-wordpress-3-9/) this outputs mangled html if you have a caption (it's pretty standard these days).

**Corrected to check if there is a caption and return the WP shortcode or if no caption, then use the figure markup. Tested and works.**

```
function html5_insert_image( $html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt ) {

    if( empty( $caption ) ) :

        $src  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, $size, false );

        $html = "<figure id=\"post-$id media-$id\" class=\"align-$align\">";

        if ( $url ) {
            $html .= "<a href=\"$url\" class=\"image-link\"><img src=\"$src[0]\" width=\"$src[1]\" height=\"$src[2]\" alt=\"$alt\" /></a>";
        } else {
            $html .= "<img src=\"$src[0]\" width=\"$src[1]\" height=\"$src[2]\" alt=\"$alt\" />";
        }

        $html .= "</figure>";

    endif;

    return $html;

}
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'html5_insert_image', 10, 9 );
```

Comment: Hi, in your 1. code it outputs also the default caption AND the figcaption... not so good. In the 2. Code it does what you say - but my goal is to replace the default function and remove the caption especially. In the first code it outputs: `[caption id="attachment_29897" align="alignnone" width="340"]<figure id="post-29897 media-29897" class="align-none"><img src="anyurl" width="340" height="340" alt="alttext" /><figcaption>captiontext</figcaption></figure> captiontex[/caption]`

Comment: I wrote that it would not work when html5 caption support was enabled. I put only the working code in the example.  Update your question more clearly and perhaps someone else will help you.

Comment: Ok thx. i missed that. best